# Do probability laws hold in case of empirical probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let the situation be that $8$ out of $20$ parts are detected defective by person $A$ and $9$ out of $20$ parts are detected defective by a person $B.$ Furthermore, $\dfrac{12}{20}$ parts are detected defective by at least one of the two persons.

So $P(A) = \dfrac{8}{20}$ & $P(B) = \dfrac{9}{20}$ & $P(A \cup B) = \dfrac{12}{20}.$

Obviously, the probabilities provided here are empirical probabilities.

Now, if one were to calculate $P(A \cap B),$ one would think that $P(A) \times P(B)$ will produce the answer since both $A$ & $B$ are independent events.

Another way to calculate $P(A \cap B)$ would be $P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B).$

Both the ways yield different results and my teacher said the second way was correct. Why is the first method not valid?

Comment: Independence of events $A$ and $B$ is *defined* by the property that $\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A) \Pr(B)$. Hence, you can have two events that intuitively seem independent (such as the case you state), but do not satisfy the aforementioned property, and hence are not independent.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the concept of "conditional independence". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$ holds for all events, and, in case $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, but then, since the other formula *always* holds, we would have
$$
P(A)P(B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B),
$$
so if these two results are different, you've proven that $A$ and $B$ are *not* independent events (or, in this case, empirically independent, I guess).

Note that the fact that $A$ and $B$ correspond to different observers does 
not necessarily make them independent - even from a philosophical stand point. The two people can have looked at the same parts, for instance, or one person can tell the other person about their findings.

Comment: could you please elaborate on the intuitive explanation as to why are they dependent events? If a person picks a part as defective, the other person has the exact same sample space to pick randomly from.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same space to pick randomly from". I'm just saying: Say you are having two doctors $D_1$ and $D_2$ measure the heights of twenty people. Then are the measurements of $D_1$ and $D_2$, heuristically speaking, independent? Well, if they are measuring the *same* people, then surely not, because if you tell me what $D_1$ measured, I have a *really* good guess at what $D_2$ is gonna measure. If they are measuring completely unrelated people, then yes, they are independent. The measurements of $D_1$ shouldn't tell me anything.

Comment: If, on the other hand, $D_1$ measures a group of people, and $D_2$ measures their identical twins, then again, the two measurement outcomes are not gonna be independent.

Comment: if $D_1$ were to measure a person and put him back without $D_2$ knowing the person's height, would it now be a case of independent events?